# Get just the name from ldap in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, ldap

I want to diaplay all the names that match with the user provided name from a directory server using LDAP and bind it to grid view. Am able to achieve this task bt instead of just a name am getting other properties like LDAP://CN=Neha Shetty,OU=Users,OU=MUM,OU=Mumbai,OU=India,OU=APAC,OU=bunt,DC=xxx,DC=com. But i just want Neha Shetty. Here is my code

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("ADConnection");

DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

//set the search filter    
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
String UserName = txt_To.Text;
// deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(GivenName=*" + UserName + "*))";
deSearch = new DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=user)(Name=*" + UserName + "*))");
//deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
string[] arrPropertiesToLoad = { "Surname" };
deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(arrPropertiesToLoad);

//  SearchResultCollection sResultColl = deSearch.FindAll();
SearchResultCollection sResultColl;
sResultColl = deSearch.FindAll();

Gridview1.DataSource = sResultColl;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I guess the default binding of a SearchResult to a GridView will display the distinguished name of the entry. You should extract the Surname attribute value from each SearchResult (something like sResultColl.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(sr=>GetSurnameAttributValue).ToList(); ) and bind the resulting string collection to your GridView.

Answer (score 1):

```
LDAP://CN=Neha Shetty,OU=Users,OU=MUM,OU=Mumbai,OU=India,OU=APAC,OU=bunt,DC=xxx,DC=com
```

is the distinguished name of the entry, and is **always** returned in a search result that returns at least one entry. The distinguished name is used as the *primary key* for an entry in a directory.

Directories do not have *properties*, directories have *attributes* which are grouped according to *objectClasses* into *entries*; properties are single-valued attributes might be multi-valued. The LDAP client must specify which user attributes should be returned as one of the parameters of the search request.

Comment: No way to do what? If the LDAP client requires just the name, specify the attribute type as a string or an OID as one of the requested attributes. The `commonName` or `cn` attribute (which in this case is also the RDN) appears to contain a full name.

Comment: If the client desires the `cn`, just add `cn` to the misleadingly named `arrPropertiesToLoad`. Note that `cn` is multi-valued and be prepared to handle multiple values that might be returned from a search request.

Comment: I get the distinguished names along with cn . I just want the name to be displayed. That was my question. i get this -- LDAP://CN=Neha Shetty,OU=Users,OU=MUM,OU=Mumbai,OU=India,OU=APAC,OU=bunt,DC=xxx,DC=com. I want only Neha Shetty to be displayed.

Comment: Retrieve the attribute that your organization has defined contains the name to be displayed! That might be `cn` or `displayName` or something else.